# Better to use ObjectOut/InputStream or InputStreamReader / BufferedReader?

Tags: java, networking

So I made a chat application using `InputStreamReader`, `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`.

**I'm wondering:**

Would it be more efficient / better practice to use an `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`? Then I could send objects through like client information (not just Strings), right?

If so, how should I handle receiving an object? (Because it could be a String or it could be a Client object I'm sending) etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner that isn't me and I have no idea why someone copy and pasted my queston, sorry.

Comment: That question has now been moderator-deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be a bad practice to use ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, because of the following 2 reasons:

- serializing objects introduces compatibility issues if you are using 2 versions of the chat program at the same time and each version uses another version of the serialized classes.
- serialized object contain a lot of metadata (save an object to a file and take a look) that has no functional meaning, so you would be sending a lot of "meaningless" data.

If you want to send object structures between your different chat applications, use Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and:

- convert any object you send to a String
- convert any String you receive back to an object

Search the Internet how to use Jackson, this is one of the first links that showed up for me:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Of course the metadata has functional meaning. Otherwise it would not be there. The metadata isn't contained in each serialized object: it's sent separately, once per class. It is not 'meaningless'.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I assume my PrintWriter and BufferedReader work well enough.

Comment: @EJP if the metadata has a functional meaning then why does Jackson not require it?  I think if you want to send objects over the Internet, it is better to do so as JSON objects that can be understood by any programming language than as Java serialized objects with *technical* metadata that is only understood by a JVM.